# Expo Contact: Request Permission to access contact if it is status is denied

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, permissions, expo

I have a contact component that works as expected, but if a user initially denies the request to grant my app access to their contact the request is not being asked again, the contact modal instead appears empty:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync()

      if (status === "granted") {
        const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
          fields: [Contacts?.Fields?.PhoneNumbers],
        });
        if (data.length > 0) {
          setContacts(data);
        }
      }
    })();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `canAskAgain` if the permission can be requested, if not give a user option to [open](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/linking/#linkingopensettings) Settings.

> Indicates if user can be asked again for specific permission. If not, one should be directed to the Settings app in order to enable/disable the permission.

```js
const { status, canAskAgain } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync()
...
if (canAskAgain) {
  Linking.openSettings()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to install expo-linking using `npx expo install expo-linking`

```
 (async () => {
      const { status, canAskAgain } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();

      if (status === "granted") {
        const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
          fields: [Contacts?.Fields?.PhoneNumbers],
        });
        if (data.length > 0) {
          setContacts(data);
        }
      } else {
        Linking.openSettings();
      console.log(canAskAgain)
      }
    })();
  }, []);
```